# Difference of NOT IN and NOT EQUALS different behaviour in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I thought `NOT IN` behaves the same as `!=` in a query. But a query using `!=` returns more rows than a query using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT  count(A.NO)
FROM A
WHERE
A.CODE != 'a' 
AND 
A.CODE  != 'b'
AND
A.CODE  != 'c'
AND 
A.NAME  != 'd' 
AND
A.NAME  != 'e'
```

returns 1566 rows, whereas

```
SELECT  count(A.NO)
FROM A
WHERE
A.CODE NOT IN ('a','b','c')
AND
A.NAME NOT IN ('d','e')
```

returns only 1200 rows.

I suppose `NOT IN` excludes `NULL` values - would that be the only difference?

Comment: can you provide us with some demo data

Comment: If A.CODE or A.NAME has a NULL value, its ignored too in the WHERE clause

Comment: The easiest way to answer the question, is to print out the 366 rows that are in the first query but not in the second. Look at the values for A.CODE and A.NAME.

Comment: NO there is no role of null values

Comment: I can't reproduce your case. please post a test case. or just do a minus between first set of rows and second as @byteherder suggested.

Comment: I don't suppose that you've made a mistake in posting the queries and that there's actually a small difference in them in that the one does `count(A.NO)` and the other does `count(some_other_column)` and that in your data one of these two columns contains nulls while the other doesn't contain nulls (or a different number of null values)?

Comment: Please get back to us as we're all curious as to what the issue is or was! And while you've been active elsewhere on SE you haven't updated this question.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to replecate the problem using [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d801/1) simplified SQL fiddle, however, it returns the same number for both versions.

What is differant about your data?

Comment: I'm guessing the queries were slightly different -- most likely different in the column passed to the `count()` function.

Answer (score 0):

No answer but what delivers the following?

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE
A.CODE != 'a' 
AND 
A.CODE  != 'b'
AND
A.CODE  != 'c'
AND 
A.NAME  != 'd' 
AND
A.NAME  != 'e'
AND NOT (
    A.CODE NOT IN ('a','b','c')
    AND
    A.NAME NOT IN ('d','e') 
)
LIMIT 0, 20
```